# How to clear previously downloaded packages of apt-get?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I was trying to install a program using `apt-get` and it installed incorrectly. It was having some bugs. So I did `sudo apt-get purge`. Now I want to install it again but when I do `apt-get install`, it does not download new packages, it uses same old downloaded packages, unpacks it and the program again gets installed incorrectly.

How do I remove those old packages.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

I'd run `apt-get autoclean` - which will clear the cache of any software that's currently not installed. If you must go deeper, `apt-get clean` will clean your whole cache.

Comment: _"Like clean, autoclean clears out the local repository of retrieved package files. The difference is that it only removes package files that can no longer be downloaded, and are largely useless."_ - `man apt-get` The criterion for `autoclean` is that the package file is no longer available, not whether the package is currently installed. So it will, for example, remove old versions of installed packages.